# Function doesn't response in large integer values, ln[*]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have to find the largest prime factor of a number, so I wrote the code below:

```
num = int(input())
start = num-2
while start>=2:
    if num%start==0 and (2**(start-1))%start==1:
        print(start)
        break
    else:
        start-=1
```

It works when the input isn't large. Ex. 12351264 => 128659 or 13195=>29, but I entered 600851475143 and it didn't respond for 10-15 minutes so I restart the kernel. Cpu and memory usages weren't high at that moment but fans start to make a bit noise. What is the problem with the code and how can I fix it?

Note: I used Fermat’s Little Theorem in the second condition.

Comment: I might consider finding a function that can do modular exponentiation directly, since `2**600851475140` is uh...massive, to say the least.

Comment: You can use the function `pow(x,y,p)` from the `math` package to compute (x**y)%p in pretty good time. I don't remember the specifics but I'm fairly sure it's `O(log n)` time

Comment: I lied, looks like `pow` is a builtin. Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exceed MAXINT for your machine, Python converts the computations to its "large integer" mode, which is *much* slower.  You're working with a number that has a huge quantity of digits.  Instead, you need to perform your modulus operations regularly, or perform some other algorithm, to get the performance you'll need.

From [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/):

```
def big_power_mod(x, y, base)
    result = 1
     
    while y > 0:
         
        # If y is odd, multiply by x
        if y % 2 == 1:
            result *=  x

        # halve y; square x; reduce mod base
        y = y >> 1
        x *= x;
        x %= base

    return result
```

Comment: It would be more efficient and pythonic to use a py builtin for modular exponentiation than to roll it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A faster way to get the largest prime number is to find all prime numbers from smallest to largest, because you have to try only `sqrt(n)/3` numbers in the worst case.

```
def iter_factors():
    yield 2
    yield 3
    for i in count(6, 6):
        yield i - 1
        yield i + 1

def prime_factors(num):
    for i in iter_factors():
        if i*i > num:
            break
        while num % i == 0:
            yield i
            num //= i
    if num > 1:
        yield num

print(max(prime_factors(600851475143)))
```